# How do I install apps to Internal/External SD instead of Phone Storage

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean, internal-storage, internal-sd

I have a dual SIM mt6589 based Android 4.2.1 phone, and I have no idea where the apps are getting installed.

My phone has an Internal SD card(built in), An External SD card and something called Phone Storage(/data ??)

Anyway the apps are supposed to be saved to my External SD but they get saved to Phone Storage.

[image: Screenshot] [image: Screenshot] [image: Screenshot]
<sup>Screenshots (click images for larger variants)</sup>

Also the option move to External SD card is greyed out(It was available before!!).
My vold.fstab file

```
dev_mount sdcard /storage/sdcard0 emmc@fat /devices/platform/goldfish_mmc.0 /devices/platform/mtk-msdc.0/mmc_host
dev_mount sdcard2 /storage/sdcard1 auto /devices/platform/goldfish_mmc.1 /devices/platform/mtk-msdc.1/mmc_host
```

Comment: @Izzy question rephrased

Comment: Did you take a look at the tag wiki I mentioned with my previous comment? It has all the answers you need.

Comment: Ah @Izzy It answers my question, hmm looks like I can't move half the apps from my Internal Storage -_-. Also What do I do with the question ?

Comment: usually apps get installed to Internal SD(with android 4.1.2) but after updating to 4.2.1, I can install to only Phone Storage

Comment: As your question might provide a place-holder to already existing details, I composed a short answer you might want to accept/upvote, so other "searchers" can find their way and follow up. The issue from your previous comment you'll need to address to your manufacturer/ROM baker: They have disabled that functionality, Android itself still supports it (you're in good company with that, seems a few manufacturer decided to do the same).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your re-phrased question can be found in the [app2sd](/questions/tagged/app2sd) [tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/app2sd/info). In short:

- App2SD cannot move the entire app to SDCard, there are always things remaining in phone storage (e.g. data, Dalvik cache, and some more)
- There are alternative methods moving more stuff, such as e.g. [link2sd](/questions/tagged/link2sd) or [Data2SD](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=rappsd.v1)

For details, please see the linked tag-wiki.

Comment: Also there seems to be a way to extend the Phone Storage http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2296230

Comment: Not really -- it can't take stuff from nothing. That tool simply changes partitioning, taking space away from the internal SDCard and adding it to "phone storage".